Control to output transfer function
I am trying to derive control to output transfer function of phase shift full bridge converter.
Applying small signal analysis, I reach to the point/schematic as shown in the picture below:
Document calculated the control to output transfer fucntion as shown in the picture below. When I equate vin = 0 V, both sides of the transformer becomes short, so it turns out to point as shown in the picture below. But here there are 2 dependent and 2 independent source. I dont know how to deal with 4 source. Generally if I had 2 source, I was making superposition technique. How should I proceed with 4 source?

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3279135_Small-signal_analysis_of_the_phase-shifted_PWM_converter

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3279135_Small-signal_analysis_of_the_phase-shifted_PWM_converter
Considering my above question, control to output transfer function given in the picture below. I think they both connected to each other. I think first I need to understand my above question, than I can derive the transfer function as stated in the picture below. But here I couldn't understand the Zf/ (Zf+Rd). How should I come to that point?

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3279135_Small-signal_analysis_of_the_phase-shifted_PWM_converter
By the way, dv and di are given as below. These are just equations derived for the small signal model. Ho is also given below I have no question about dv, di or Ho. I just put them to show what are they.

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3279135_Small-signal_analysis_of_the_phase-shifted_PWM_converter

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3279135_Small-signal_analysis_of_the_phase-shifted_PWM_converter

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45zMW6TYpnA

Source: My own calculation

Source: my simulation

What you zero for your analysis, is $v_{in}$ which is an ac component. $V_{in}$ in the other sources is the dc value of the input source acting as coefficient. You keep it of course ^_^ If you like deriving transfer functions, you may want to look at my book from 2021 dedicated to the topic.

Sir, what do you suggest me at this stage shortly, I will be very happy if you can give some advice at this stage @VerbalKint

Yes sir, vin will be zero as you said. but ı dont now the rest, how should I apply superimposition then ? @VerbalKint

When I derive a transfer function, I usually qualify the model I want to use. In your case, you should build this equivalent ac model in LTspice, for instance, and check that you obtain the curves given in the paper. This is key to understand the architecture. It will also let you understand how the equations are built.
In 2009, I published the PWM switch model version for the phase-shifted full-bridge converter. The paper is here. I used this model to test the equivalent ac model we need for the transfer function:

In this example, I ac-modulate the \$d\$ input which is the ac part of the duty ratio and see how it propagates to generate a response at both outputs. As confirmed by the plots, all responses in magnitude and phase are the same so the model is ok.
Now, this model is complicated to solve because of the various controlled sources and the generator. I prefer merging all these sources, simplify the expression and obtain the simplest possible model. This is what I've done below:

You can see now how the model looks simpler to deal with. Now, you can either apply the Fast Analytical Circuits Techniques or FACTs or apply brute-force KVL and KCL to that circuit. Then rearrange the final expression in a low-entropy form, meaning you can see a resonant frequency and a quality factor as they've done in the paper.
If I apply the real brute-force - what I never do : ), I end up with the same expression they found, neglecting the capacitor ESR:


Sir, your comment is very valuable to me. As far as I know, you put VIL in order to represent the vs reduction due to the small amount of filter inductor current. If so how should I define VIL and I(VIL) in Ltspice in terms of equation     @VerbalKint

Hello, no, the VIL source is a dummy 0-V voltage source. It is only there to measure the inductor current $i_L$ with I(VIL) and use it in the equations. Just curious, why are looking into this converter small-signal response? By the way, if my answer meets your expectations, I would appreciate if you could kindly acknowledge it, thank you!

Sir, firstly I am a very big fan of you and your studies :) I am trying for this converter to develop feedback compansation sir. I am a self paced learner, I have no one to ask these kind of questions. @VerbalKint

I have a couple of question. You mensioned 'merging all these sources'. I simply add the voltage sources together, let the vin= 0 and I have same result as yours. For the current sources, again simply add  together, let vin= 0, this time I think you ignored the R because it is much smaller than Rd, and you reverse the current source direction by reversing the equation (instead of N*V(d)*Vin/Rl – I(VIL)*Rd) I think ?  Am I true sir ?
And we only let vin= 0, because il of di is in the control loop isn’t it sir ?
@VerbalKint

Yes, I did reverse the source because of the neg. sign and two sources in series are merged into one. $v_{in}$ is zero because when you ac-modulate the duty ratio $d$, the input voltage source is constant to a dc value $V_{in}$ and is thus 0 V in ac.

Thank you so much sir, I understand the calculation of the last picture however another question come to my mind. We only considered the voltage source at the last simplified version and let the current source be open and we develop the equations based on this. Why we didnt consider the current source? in this case we could short the voltage source and develop the eqautions based on the current source . At the the and we could add the results which is one for voltage and one for current source. But we didnt. What is the reason for this sir ?   @VerbalKint

The current source has no effect in this mode, the voltage source drives the voltage across its terminals. If you simulate the circuit in LTspice, you can run the simulation with and without the current source, it has no effect in this particular configuration.

Hello sir, I made a calculation for uncompensated loop gain . I add 2 picture above at the end. 1'st is to show loop gain and the 2'nd is to show loop gain/ phase plot. In the 2'nd picture (last picture), first plot is for gain, the middle plot is for phase asymptotes of Quadratic poles and zero seperately and the last plot is for general phase of the T(s). I compared the last phase diagram with yours as only DC gain will change . It is similar with yours however I dont have a roll-off after the zero. What do you think about the asymtotes sir ? Does it look good sir ?  @VerbalKint

Hello, the best is to capture the circuit and run its ac simulation with LTspice. It is the fastest and most efficient way to check your drawing.

Hello sir, thank you so much for everything, I know that I bother you so much, forgive me sir. I simulate the circuit (only control to output) with my parameters and I add the circuit / results above in  the last picture. The gain and phase look weird, it seems there is no dc gain for low frequency, on the other hand phase seems upside down. It is kind of strange to me, where do I make mistake sir ? circuit setup looks fine but the result is interesting @VerbalKint

Hello, please try first to simulate the exact same circuit I used for illustrating the post (with the same components values) and ac-sweep from 10 to 100 kHz.

Yes sir, I simulated your circuit values and the results are same as yours. But when I use my values result are very weird, what could be the reason for this sir ? @VerbalKint

The turns ratio is 1:N in my models, so if you have 21, N should be 1/21 = 47.6m.

Hello sir, forgive me. I couldn't explain myself. My turns ratio is 21:1 . I got the same results as your with your parameters however  my issue is when I use my parameters the plot is kind of weird, it seems everything is upside down. This is the point  that ı would like to ask sir @VerbalKint

Sir, would you like to help me about my last question @Verbal Kint
