Calculation of control to output transfer function
EXPLANATION
Picture 1 is control to output transfer function. (For those wondering how I obtained this formula, you can check Control to output transfer function. This formula was obtained with the help of VerbalKint.)
Picture 2 is my calculations about pole, dc gain, zero and phase.
Picture 3 is the LTspice simulation.
Note: Question is very easy to follow for those who knows the calculation of transfer function.
QUESTION
The LTspice calculation seems correct but I have mistakes in handmade calculation.

As seen in my calculation, Q value is 1.033x10^-5, which is -99.71 dB. Why does Q have such a strange value?
I found the phase asymptote values ​​for quadratic pole as 0 degrees and 10^48402, which is infinite. I cannot find the correct phase break points, where am I making a mistake?
It seems the the phase of zero starts at 340 Hz and ends at 34 kHz. It doesn't match with the LTspice result.

So basically what is wrong with my calculation?
Picture 1. Control to Output Transfer Function

Answer to "https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/728110/control-to-output-transfer-function'' by Verbal Kint, edited by Mhan and posted on Software Engineering Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0.
Picture 2: My calculations


Picture 3: LTspice simulation


I would recommend you use SPICE notations for inductance or capacitance like 2 uH or 7 mF for instance, not 0.000002 or 0.007 which is difficult to read and prone to mistakes if you miss a 0. By the way, where is your ac source in the circuit?

The Ac source was inside the schematic just outside, I updated the picture. I tried your suggestion , nothing changed sir. I tried to ask this question to you many times but I couldn't get any answer from you. This transfer function is produced by you for my application so when I put my aplication values the mathematical calculation doesn't fit with Ltspice? Did you check my handmade calculation? they are just a standart calculation. Where is my mistake in the calculation ? @Verbal Kint

The Q value is weird, the phase of quadratic pole is weird and phase of the zero is not matching with the Ltspice @Verbal Kint

I will try to have a look. Please narrow down the ac plot from 10 Hz to 100 kHz, no need to go down to the mHz.

Ok, I am very exited to see your suggestion about my calculation. I am just trying to find the mistake in handmade universal calculation to match it with the Ltspice ? @Verbal Kint

Before proceeding, did you run a cycle-by-cycle (transient) simulation to check whether all the values you have put in this ac model lead to a consistent operating point? This is the starting point before considering an ac sweep. Like $V_{out}$ is ok, the duty ratio seems fine etc. I see a 390-V input voltage with a 500-ohm load but the model implies a high-power CCM mode. What are the expected output voltage and power here?

I didn't run transient analysis sir because I followed your instructions in my previous question which is linked in the question. The output is 12V and 600W expected. Now when I run '' .tran 60s '' in Ltspice,  I got 0 V. Should I make any change while doing transient analysis ?  Additionally, my main issue is my handmade calculation because I have a weird Q and phase results on the paper given in the question.  @Verbal Kint

I see, if the output voltage is 12 V, then for a 600-W output power the load should be 240 mOhms and not 500 ohms as in your sim. If you want to check the operating point, I am talking about a real switching circuit, not an averaged model. Check my free platforms in SIMPLIS, there is phase-shifted converter.

The first thing to do, is to run a cycle-by-cycle simulation and verify the converter actually delivers the power. You can use the example from my free ready-made templates, it works on the free demo version of SIMPLIS:

So we have 12 V with a 240-mOhm load from a 390-V source so all is ok.
Then, run the averaged model now that you are confident with the adopted components values. As I said, use SPICE notations for clearer inspection:

The right-side plot compares the ac response from SIMPLIS and that of the averaged model. Both responses agree very well. The average model should include a pure delay as shown in my original document.
Finally, you have different expressions for plotting the responses and all are very close to each other:

Hope it's now ok with you and you can relax : )
